# python websocket failure when run in openshift

Tags: python, kubernetes, openshift, twisted, autobahn

I have a autobahn twisted websocket running in python which is working in a dev vm correctly but I have been unable to get working when the server is running in openshift.

Here is the shortened code which works for me in a vm.

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory, listenWS
from autobahn.twisted.resource import WebSocketResource

class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def onConnect(self, request):
        stuff...
    def onOpen(self):
        stuff...
    def onMessage(self,payload):
        stuff...


factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://0.0.0.0:8080")
factory.protocol = MyServerProtocol
resource = WebSocketResource(factory)

root = File(".")
root.putChild(b"ws", resource)
site = Site(root)

reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

The connection part of the client is as follows:

```
var wsuri;
var hostname = window.document.location.hostname;
wsuri = "ws://" + hostname + ":8080/ws";

if ("WebSocket" in window) {
    sock = new WebSocket(wsuri);
} else if ("MozWebSocket" in window) {
    sock = new MozWebSocket(wsuri);
} else {
    log("Browser does not support WebSocket!");
    window.location = "http://autobahn.ws/unsupportedbrowser";
}
```

The openshift configuration is as follows:

1 pod running with app.py listening on port 8080 
tls not enabled
I have a non-tls route 8080 > 8080.

Firefox gives the following message in the console:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://openshiftprovidedurl.net:8080/ws.
```

when I use wscat to connect to the websocket.

```
wscat -c ws://openshiftprovidedurl.net/ws
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Error: unexpected server response (400)
```

and the application log in openshift shows the following:

```
2018-04-03 01:14:24+0000 [-] failing WebSocket opening handshake ('missing port in HTTP Host header 'openshiftprovidedurl.net' and server runs on non-standard port 8080 (wss = False)')
2018-04-03 01:14:24+0000 [-] dropping connection to peer tcp4:173.21.2.1:38940 with abort=False: missing port in HTTP Host header 'openshiftprovidedurl.net' and server runs on non-standard port 8080 (wss = False)
2018-04-03 01:14:24+0000 [-] WebSocket connection closed: connection was closed uncleanly (missing port in HTTP Host header 'openshiftprovidedurl.net' and server runs on non-standard port 8080 (wss = False))
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: A quick look at code suggest you somehow need to work out how to set ``externalPort`` to 80 when endpoint setup. https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/7844219a8f299b9a378672d8e07e6cfb70ed6551/autobahn/websocket/interfaces.py#L71

Answer (score 4):

Graham Dumpleton hit the nail on the head, I modified the code from

```
factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://0.0.0.0:8080")
```

to

```
factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://0.0.0.0:8080", externalPort=80)
```

and it corrected the issue.  I had to modify my index to point to the correct websocket but I am now able to connect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code of `autobahn-python`, you can get that message only in 2 cases.

Here is the [implementation](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/autobahn/websocket/protocol.py):

```
if not ((self.factory.isSecure and self.factory.externalPort == 443) or (not self.factory.isSecure and self.factory.externalPort == 80)):
                    return self.failHandshake("missing port in HTTP Host header '%s' and server runs on non-standard port %d (wss = %s)" % (str(self.http_request_host), self.factory.externalPort, self.factory.isSecure))
```

Because I think you are using Deployment + Service (and maybe Ingress on top of them) for your server, you can bind your server to port `80` instead of `8080` and set that port in Service and in Ingress, if you are using them.

Comment: If using S2I based images under OpenShift, you can't bind to port 80 in the container as you are not allowed to run as ``root``. Running stuff as ``root`` when there is no good reason is always a bad idea. Instead, the S2I images are always set up to use port 8080. You need a way of telling the application that it is okay that external port used by external routing layer is port 80, even though internally the container uses port 8080.